# How to start and shutdown tomcat 7 server in Linux 12.04?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

How to start and shutdown tomcat server in Linux 12.04?

When I have used `sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat7 restart`, it is working.

When I have used `service tomcat7 restart`, I am getting the message:

> you need root privileges to run this script.

When I have used `/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/shutdown.sh`, I am getting:

> org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
>   WARNING: Problem with JAR file [/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/commons-dbcp.jar], exists: [false],                    canRead: [false]

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information on this. Cause with the provided information I would just `sudo shutdown -r 0` to restart the whole system.

I can tell that you are using Ubuntu 12.04 based on 'Linux 12.04'. In Ubuntu you should add `sudo` when running commands as root, check [this](http://linux.about.com/cs/linux101/g/sudo.htm). To understand this read on file permissions, check [this](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions). Hope I saved some googling!